# Does anyone know how to fix a keyword argument 'deny_new' errror in Discord Rewrite? (I have latest version)

Tags: python, discord.py

ERROR:

```
 TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'
```

I am having the same error as well and I am upgraded to the latest version. I tried reinstalling it after removing it (with pip cache clear) but that also did not work. It only works when I run the python file from command prompt.
[Error screenshot (I could not copy and paste it here because it closes so fast)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBVhH.jpg)

Comment: Checkout this issue: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5160

Answer (score 0):

Update your discord.py

```py
pip install -U discord.py
```

Alternatives are

```py
python -m pip install discord.py -U --user
pip install discord.py -U --user
```

If nothing works, force update it to 1.4.0 as its the latest version

Comment: This did not work. I already tried that exact command.